# Why is Outlook breaking my Microdata?

Tags: outlook, html-email, microdata

So, for our email newsletter we have started marking up with structured data using Microdata (with the schema.org vocabulary).

Here is an example of a line of code in the design:

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Restaurant">
```

However, on arrival in Outlook 2013 using Exchange 2012 the code appears as:

```html
<span itemscopeitemtype="https://schema.org/Restaurant">
```

Note the space has been taken away after `itemscope` - this basically breaks the code and all data markup is ignored.  Any ideas out there as to why?

I know Outlook isn't our primary market for this data, but it is irritating that it is getting broken and I'd love to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of message bodies. All supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties are described in the following articles in MSDN:

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but it looks like this has been fixed in Exchange 2013. The `itemscope` attribute arrives with the value set to the empty string (which is [according to spec](https://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#attributes-0)): `itemscope=""`.

In earlier versions of Exchange I would suggest setting the value explicitly.